# How to get Matlab to determine if the OS is windows, or mac? So to find all serial-usb connections

Tags: windows, macos, matlab, serial-port, usbserial

**Description of goal:**

I'm trying to get matlab to determine if the computer is running windows, or mac. My main goal for this is to write a robust script to determine what serial ports are available, and USB ports (for the same reason) to identify which is an Arduino.

**Current work:**

I have a script that queries the registry on Windows and successfully identifies this information. However, I'm trying to make this script robust and identify for both mac and windows.

**Request:**
If there is a better way to do this in matlab? And how do I do it robustly, hopefully independent of OS if possible, or if not, how do I do this on a Mac! Note, (instrfindall) only identifies objects to ports, which are therefore already open. So it is sadly not a solution.

EDIT: I can determine if it's MAC or WINDOWS via ismac, and ispc calls. However, the main guts of this question still remains!

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/33273-scanports-function-scans-for-available-serial-ports Is this script universal to Windows and Mac?

Comment: Sadly, no :( I just tried it. But if you read it, it's searching for 'COM' ports. That's how they're addressed in windows. They're labelled and referenced completely different in mac -_- but thank you for your advice!

Comment: I've never been a serious Mac user so forgive me no knowledge at all. But in my view you can simply change the script a little bit to include Mac devices? http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/serial.html Here the references are listed.

Comment: If you want to make your script "independent of OS", then avoid registry queries since Windows may change the commands/API's across versions. Instead, try using Matlab commands as the answers suggest. It seems impossible to name serial ports in Windows and Mac in the same way, so you may still have to include both versions of code. Try `switch` :)

Comment: That is the plan. But still yet to find a way to determine the serial ports.

Answer (score 6):

Even easier. MATLAB has a [method](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ispc.html?searchHighlight=ispc&s_tid=doc_srchtitle) to flag each OS without going to the level of CPU architecture.

```matlab
if ismac
    % Code to run on Mac platform
elseif isunix
    % Code to run on Linux platform
elseif ispc
    % Code to run on Windows platform
else
    disp('Platform not supported')
end
```

Note: I am a MathWorks employee.

Comment: Nice to have a MathWorks employee here! A question: If MATLAB cannot run on unsupported platforms, what is the point of the last `else`?

Comment: Thanks! This is meant for illustration though in some cases due to lack of testing, hardware or underlying MATLAB support there will be situations where a platform will not be supported.

Answer (score 2):

The MATLAB command you need to identify OS is `computer`

For example, on a Mac:

```
>> computer

ans =

MACI64
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! This is also an option, however, I edited it because I learned of the ispc ismac command. So if you have any idea of the bulk of my question that'd be awesome!

Answer (score 2):

This is simple.

You need to use the function ispc. The reference is http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ispc.html.

Returns 0 if Mac and 1 if Windows.

Serial port:http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/serial-port-devices.html. Read up on this.

Comment: Thanks for your help! This is also an option, however, I edited it because I learned of the ispc ismac command. So if you have any idea of the bulk of my question that'd be awesome!

Answer (score 2):

The command from inside `MATLAB` is `computer`. The following returns the value `MACI` which is for Mac OS X (Intel):

```
>> c = computer;
>> 

c =

MACI

>>
```

Type `help computer` for more.

Comment: Thanks for your help! This is also an option, however, I edited it because I learned of the ispc ismac command. So if you have any idea of the bulk of my question that'd be awesome!

Answer (score 1):

If you have instrument control toolbox you may check the
[instrhwinfo](http://www.mathworks.com/help/instrument/instrhwinfo.html) function to get available serial ports.

If not I would suggest to go to system command.
For example, on windows you may parse output of the `mode` command:

```
[status,cmdout] = system('mode');
```

Variable `cmdout` will contain something like this:

```
Status for device CON:
----------------------
    Lines:          2048
    Columns:        200
    Keyboard rate:  31
    Keyboard delay: 1
    Code page:      866
```

for each device like serial ports and LPT ports.
I'm not MAC user, but I suspect you may find something similar there too.

**UPD1**

I do not think that this way you can distinguish between real serial ports and USB-to-serial adapters, but it should give you list of available serial ports at the moment you call the `mode` function.

Comment: I'll basically send a message to all and see if I get the designated response(if any) to determine if it's the correct one (unless), like on windows, I can identify the device name and decide if it's the correct device that way. I will give this a look into! And let you know what I find, thank you :)